# Stuck at resolution 1024X768

Tags: display-resolution

Today my Ubuntu installation went into 1024X786.
At first installing the latest nvidia driver solver the problem and now it is no longer working after a weird crash.

The driver is properly installed:

```
Fri Apr 16 00:03:05 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.56       Driver Version: 460.73.01    CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 107...  Off  | 00000000:09:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 39%   36C    P0    37W / 180W |      0MiB /  8116MiB |      2%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the following two steps:

`sudo apt purge nvidia*` from a terminal.

And then went [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/tesla/tesla-installation-notes/index.html#ubuntu-lts) and did this:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
distribution=$(. /etc/os-release;echo $ID$VERSION_ID | sed -e 's/\.//g')
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/$distribution/x86_64/cuda-$distribution.pin
sudo mv cuda-$distribution.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/$distribution/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
echo "deb http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/$distribution/x86_64 /" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install cuda-drivers
```

This worked for me. Let me know if it did the trick.

Comment: `sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/$distribution/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub` does not work on Ubuntu 22.04, now I need to get rid of this repository entry in apt

Answer (score 0):

dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` (and then possibly restart) to correct the problem.